# El método onActivityResult no recive los extras de mi intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Estoy intentando, a partir de una imagen de la galería, cortarla en cuadrado y mostrarla en un `imageView`. Hasta aquí todo bien, he encontrado en muchos sitios cómo hacerlo. El problema llega cuando en el método `onActivityResult` debo obtener los datos de mi `intent`, el que llega aquí no tiene extras de ningún tipo. Al no recibirme los extras no me deja obtener la imagen.

Ya no sé qué más probar. He probado incluso imprimir simplemente una palabra para comprobar si me recibe los datos y no hay manera.

Os incluyo el código de lo que estoy probando. Es más, si alguien lo busca por internet lo he sacado de un tutorial en el que sí funciona y hay varios ejemplos más por internet en el que esto mismo funciona.

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imgview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

                try {

                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), 2);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            if (extras2 != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acostumbrate a utilizar log.d(TAG,"lo que sea") despues de onActivityResult es llamado.

Comment: Si, si lo uso lo que pasa es que aqui no esta. Una vez que entra en el onActivityResult, llega al segundo if, entra y hasta ahi, a if(extras2 != null) no llega a entrar puesto que extras2 es null, no hay nada.

Comment: Pon un Log dentro del onActivityResult para saber si entra o no al método, de igual manera puedes loguear el resultCode y el requestCode para que revises el porque salta tus validaciones en caso de que si entre al método

Comment: Ya lo probé, en el método entra y el resultCode y requestCode también son correctos.

Comment: @garodev, entonces el problema en realidad es el código para agregar la imagen en el ImageView,

Comment: @Elenasys el problema lo tengo en:   Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras(); Mostrar la imagen puedo con el código que me ha indicado Bourne en el primer comentario pero lo que necesito son los extras que le paso al Intent. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

ok ya hice el ejemplo y me funciono implementandolo de la siguiente manera

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        Uri imageSelected = data.getData();
        if (imageSelected != null) {
            try {
                imgview.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageSelected));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso funciona, muchas gracias, ya es mas de lo que yo conseguí. Pero, lo que yo necesitaba era también recortarla de ahí que usara el "getParceable" que se supone que con los extras que yo puse debería funcionar. De todas formas con esto ya mostrándose la imagen voy a seguir probando a ver si lo consigo.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** Al ejecutar [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)), estas enviando un `requestCode` con valor `2` , este  `requestCode` es retornado en `onActivityResult()` de la Activity que realiza el `Intent` :

```
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), 2);
```

Entonces en tu `onActivityResult()` solo detecta el valor :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 2) {
           //  Realiza tarea!
        }
    }
```

**B)** En cuanto a que no recibes los datos del bundle, tu estas realizando un intent para abrir un Chooser usando [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) :

```
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 2);
```

en este caso no existe razón para agregar estos valores:

```
 intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
 intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
 intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
 intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
```

Pero tienes otro detalle si intentas recibir en el bitmap en el bundle de esta forma:

```
  Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data")
```

Eso se puede realizando el Intent de esta forma:

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 2);
```

y para recibir el bitmap simplememente:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) { 
       //Obtiene extras y bitmap del Bundle.
       Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
       Bitmap bm = extras.getParcelable("data");
       imgview.setImageBitmap(bm);
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, ahi me entra siempre pero no obtiene los extras, el codigo que hay dentro de ese if.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona bien el siguiente codigo:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PHOTO_CODE:
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{mPath}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                            }
                        });
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                mSetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;
            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri path = data.getData();
                mSetImage.setImageURI(path);
                break;

         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero eso solo muestra la imagen, yo necesito los extras del intent para conseguir una imagen cortada en cuadrado.